# How To Access Exchange 2003 Private (Contact) Items Programmatically

Tags: .net, exchange-server-2003

I'm looking for a way to programmatically (.Net) access PRIVATE contact folders on an Exchange 2003 server, to create a subfolder where to create contacts from a database.

The solutions I found so far rely on EWS, e.g. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/aec6c998-f304-439c-9fa7-27bb9a4c4b45/problem-accessing-folders-in-another-mailbox?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment - such examples work for 2007+, the Exchange server I have to target is 2003.

Other examples are outlook Addins.

I need a standalone solution (an executable) that each time it runs, it's creating contacts from a DB into a particular subfolder under user's Contacts folder.

I also searched for some MAPI code samples (.Net) without much luck.

Could you please provide code (either VB.NET or C#) illustrating how to access a private mailbox Contacts folder (or a subfolder), to write a new contact item there?

Comment: Entirely stand-alone is going to be problematic, but have a look at Redemption Data Objects which exposes the CDO/RDO mechanism used by outlook. It does require Outlook to be installed, but doesn't require it to be running (it uses libraries, it doesn't automate it). We recently started using it and are getting much better performance than EWS. http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdo_introduction.htm Even if you don't use that, grab a (free) copy of OutlookSpy, it will expose a lot of info about how Exchange works internally (adds a toolbar to outlook)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @John Saunders: Thanks for your efforts to enforce compliance. In my particular case I felt that the removed ".Net" from the title was essential to emphasize that I don't need to receive C++/java etc. solutions, but .Net only. I guess some people might consider it obvious because of  the ".net" tag. Does a tag have the meaning of "only" XOR "nice to have" ... unless otherwise explicitly explained?

Comment: Since you used the .NET tag, anyone would be in error to give you a Java or C++ answer.

Comment: I think the question I should have asked in the first place is: "Is it possible to write a Contact item into another user's mailbox, in a subfolder under their Contacts folder, using Outlook interop, provided that my user has full rights to the other user's mailbox?" Please feel free to respond. Thanks :-)

Comment: @Basic: thanks for pointing me into the right direction. I ended up using RDO, no security issues. Please provide your comment as an answer, so that I can accept it. Thanks :-)

Comment: @Miha No worries - and thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Promoted from a comment]

Entirely stand-alone is going to be problematic, but have a look at [Redemption Data Objects](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdo_introduction.htm) which exposes the CDO/RDO mechanism used by outlook. It does require Outlook to be installed, but doesn't require it to be running (it uses the libraries, but doesn't work by automating Outlook).

We recently started using RDO and are getting much better performance than EWS.

Even if you don't use that, grab a (free) copy of [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/home.htm) by the same company. It will expose a lot of info about how Exchange works internally, especially the data structures is uses (It adds a toolbar to Outlook, it's not stand alone).

Comment: There should be a tick under the post score on the left hand side. Click it to accept. See [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/135956) and [How does “Reputation” work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/135956) for some site basics

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do it from .Net, then you probably need to use the Outlook object as described [in the conclusion to the Using MAPI to Create Outlook 2007 Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678348(v=office.12).aspx#olUsingMAPI_Conclusion) article on MSDN. CDO and RDO are meant to be used with VBscript and other unmanaged code.

Using this method, you're using C# to leverage Outlook 2007 (or better) automation in the given mailbox. Yes, it would require an account that would have appropriate access permissions to the target mailbox, and you'd have to iterate through the mailboxes and navigate the folder tree yourself.

The example they give is this:

```
private void AddContact()
{
    try
    {
        Outlook.ContactItem oContact =
            Application.CreateItem(
            Outlook.OlItemType.olContactItem)
            as Outlook.ContactItem;
        oContact.FirstName = "Jacqueline";
        oContact.LastName = "Haddad";
        oContact.Initials = "J.H.";
        oContact.CompanyName = "Microsoft";
        oContact.Email1Address = "someone@example.com";
        oContact.Email1AddressType = "SMTP";
        oContact.Email1DisplayName =
            "Jacqueline Haddad (someone@example.com)";
        oContact.BusinessAddressStreet = "1 Microsoft Way";
        oContact.BusinessAddressCity = "Redmond";
        oContact.BusinessAddressState = "WA";
        oContact.BusinessAddressPostalCode = "95802";
        oContact.BusinessAddressCountry = "USA";
        oContact.BusinessTelephoneNumber = "800-555-1212";
        oContact.WebPage = "http://www.codeplex.com/mfcmapi";
        oContact.Body = "This is a sample note.";
        oContact.Save();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: The other implication is that you'd need to have Outlook installed and the appropriate profile configured on the machine you're running this tool from.